# How to give some variables "constant status" that are read from a fixed memory area in the beginning of a embedded program?

Tags: c

Detail of the problem:

Some variables are read from a fixed memory area in RAM into an array. From that array I need to read some variables and use it across the code but these variables need to be constant as they wont be changed in the program any where. Need suggestions to do it effectively! Thanks in advance for any help.

The thought was given for using const variables but then Const variables needs to be initialised during declaration itself. I need to extract bit by bit for each of these variables as I am not able to use memcpy for ensuring portability. Hence I find trouble in declaring the variables as constant.

Comment: Have you tried `const`?

Comment: Const variables needs to be initialised during declaration itself. I need to extract bit by bit for each of these variables as I am not able to use memcpy for ensuring portability. Hence I find trouble in declaring the variables as constant.

Comment: What are you using that `memcpy` isn’t portable to? You can just implement `memcpy`…

Comment: Store them in non-const variables with unlikely names, and use const pointers to them for everybody to access

Comment: Seems like a possible solution...

Answer (score 0):

Put those variables {myVar1, myVar2,...myVarN} into a C file myconsts.c (static to the compilation unit, this will make sure they are not visible outside). Add a header file myconsts.h with function declarations

```
int getmyVar1(void);
```

and so on for all the variables and implement the functions in myconsts.c.

They aren't const in the C sense, but they are unwriteable from outside the myconsts.c file. You can initialise them inside myconsts.c, just dont forget to call the init().

If you mean that you are trying to guarantee that these 'constants' end up in flash as opposed to your RAM memory...consult your manual.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline functions to access the data direct from the array, e.g

> static inline myvar() { return array[myvaroffset]; }

Or, if you want the offsets hidden, don't use inline functions and just have a small module that just provides the functions.

If 'myvaroffset' is calculated rather than being a constant and you want to avoid the indexing overhead, copy the array element to a variable during initialisation and return that from the function. If you use real functions, the variables can be static within the function module.

in the function module

> /* initialisation */
>
> static int myvarlocal = array[myvaroffset];
>
> ...
>
> /* function definitions */
>
> ...
>
> int myvar() { return myvarlocal; }

When you want to use it:

> i = myvar();

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no need to make things complicated with const pointers etc. Simply use private encapsulation:

// data.h

```
int data_get (int index);
```

// data.c

```
#include "data.h"

static int the_array [N];

int data_get (int index)
{
  if(index >= N)
  {
    // handle errors
  }

  return array[index];
}
```